# Use custom deserializer in jackson fasterxml

Tags: fasterxml, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have an xml file like:

```
<users>
    <user>
        <name>User</name>
        <details>
            <age>15</age>
            ...
        </details>
    </user>
    ...
</users>
```

I want to map this xml to List, where User class defined as:

```
class User {
    public String userName;
    public int userAge;
}
```

I don't want to define mapping using annotations and so on. Just want to create an custom deserializer. I know that It is possible in Jackson for json to define custom deserializer by extending the JsonDeserializer.

Is there similar possibility for xml deserialization?

Comment: Are you not wanting to change your Java model?